# Object.assign recursive does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming

I have the following function:

```js
const test = (i, o) => {
  if (i < 1)
    return o
  else
    return Object.assign(o, test(i - 1, ({
      value: i,
      label: i
    })))
}

console.log(test(5, ({})))
```

And i except it to print:

```
[
    { value: '1', label: '1' },
    { value: '2', label: '2' },
    { value: '3', label: '3' },
    { value: '4', label: '4' },
    { value: '5', label: '5' }
]
```

However the result is:

```
{ value: 1, label: 1 }
```

What's wrong with recursive Object.assign?

Comment: What purpose does your funcion have?

Comment: `value` and `label` are constantly being overwritten with the recursive call, so you get only the deepest value. You're not creating an Array if that's what you intended.

Comment: put console.log into else

Comment: @connexo i want to construct a large object with up-counting values, i want to use it in a html table later on. I know i could do it with a for loop, however i thought it should be possible with recursion, or at least i don't know why it should not work with recursion.

Comment: Please refer to [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)'s documentation. This is now how it works.

Comment: @Jeto i already read it, Object.assign is intended to return the value, exactly what i need.

Comment: recursion doesn't change the nature of an object, which can have only a single value for each property. If you need multiple `value/label` properties, then you need an array of objects, or a single object with an array for each of those props.

Comment: Add `console.log(o)` as first line of your test method and you will get what is happening.

Comment: and what result do you expect? object can only have one `value` key, so it's `1` at the end of recusion.

Comment: @NiVeR then i get: { value: 5, label: 5 }
{ value: 4, label: 4 }
{ value: 3, label: 3 }
{ value: 2, label: 2 }
{ value: 1, label: 1 }

Comment: @dfsq i want multiple Object.assigns recursivley

Comment: So your answer is not getting `appended` but `replaced`.

Comment: You keep overwriting `value` and `label` in the single object you're working on.

Comment: So the deepest recursive call gets (and returns) `{ value: 1, label: 1 }`, which results in `Object.assign({ value: 2, label: 2 }, { value: 1, label: 1 })`. So what is the result of that `.assign()` call?

Comment: @doodlemeister Object.assign({ value: 2, label: 2 }, { value: 1, label: 1 }) = {value: 1, label: 1} okay that doesn't make sense to me

Comment: One more time: you need to show what you want to receive, post example of expected output, then you will get the answer. Right now it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's how that method works. The properties of the right most objects are assigned to the left. So returning that value results in `Object.assign({ value: 3, label: 3 }, { value: 1, label: 1 })`. What is the result of that `.assign()` call?

Comment: @dfsq i wrote "And i except it to print (Object):" thats exactly what i expect

Comment: Haha, so you wanted array of objects? :D This is very misleading question.

Comment: @dfsq i just clarified it

Comment: FYI, you can certainly do it with recursion too. You just don't need `Object.assign` to do it. `const test = (i, a) => {
  if (i < 1)
    return a
  else
    return  a.concat(test(i - 1, a), {value:i, label:i})
}

console.log(test(5, []))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this could make sense is having an array as your result.

Here's a possible solution:

```js
function test(length) {
  return [...Array(length).keys()]
    .map(i => ({value: i + 1, label: i + 1}))
}

console.log(test(5));
```

Comment: thx that was what i was looking for, i guess my question was not very precise sorry for that

Comment: @madknight No problem, happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want recursion here:

```
 const test = (i, o) => (i ? test(i - 1, o) : []).concat(Object.assign({}, o, { value: i, label: i }));
```

Comment: since i use lodash/fp, the shortest solution that i came up with is const test = l => range(0, l).map(i => ({value: i + 1, label: i + 1})) (based on the previous answer)

Comment: Try to make it tail recursive so that you can combine it with a trampoline.